# Is the following Area of Crescent all right?

Tags: geometry, area

In the figure below. There are two overlapping circles and the area of Crescent in Red that I have found is $A_{C} = \frac{\pi rw}{2}$, where $w$ is the shift from center $'X'$ in blue to $'X'$ in red.

Details:
$$A_C = \frac{A_{elipse} - A_{circle}}{2} = \frac{[\pi r^2 + \pi r w] - \pi r^2}{2}$$

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WLOG, assume both centers lie on the $x$-axis. You can use this diagram afterwards:

[image]

Since the area of the circle is $A=\pi r^2$, then the area of the crescent should be:
$$A_{\text{crescent}}=\pi r^2-(2A_{\text{sector }EAF}-2A_{\triangle AEF})$$

This is because $A_{\text{sector }EAF}=A_{\text{sector }ECF}$, and so does their corresponding triangle. Since the area of a sector is $A=\frac12r^2 \theta$, with $\theta$ in radians, and the area of the triangle is $A=\frac12ab\sin C$. Then the area of the crescent can be re-written as:
$$A=\pi r^2-\alpha r^2+r^2\sin\alpha\\
\implies A=r^2(\pi-\alpha+\sin \alpha)$$

Comment: hmm...Thanks for your solution. On a sidenote, what software have you used for drawing your figures. It seems very elegant for technical writings. It seems your answer is correct. I will notify it as solution after solving it myself as well ^_^

Comment: This is just Geogebra online.

Answer (score 3):

Note that for $w=r$ we obtain

$$A_C=\frac{\pi r^2}{2}$$

which seems to be wrong.

Moreover how does the area for the ellipse come in the derivation?

For the general formula refer to [Circle overlapping](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html).

Comment: hmm..thanks for notifying. 
I thought since both circles are of same radius, a slight shift would mean that they move as if formning ellipse. But I can see how you are right and I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome! Bye